# Get specific taxonomy terms of current post hierarchical

Tags: php, wordpress

I have searched the internet for direction and help with this but cannot find anything. I am trying to get all the terms of the current post by a specific taxonomy 'attribute'. But I need each depth level to be separated by custom html markup for the table layout I am trying to setup. You will see by my code below. The code below works on getting it all the way I way except its getting all terms from all posts from taxonomy attribute instead of only the ones from the current post, any suggestions, any help would be god sent at this point!

```
      $attribute_ids = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'attribute', array('fields' => 'ids') );

      $attributes = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy'          => 'attribute',
        'hide_empty'        => true,
        //'fields'            => 'all',
        //'taxonomy'          => 'attribute',
        'parent'            => 0,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        //'child_of'          => 0,
        'include'           => $attribute_ids,
        'orderby'           => 'term_id',
        'order'             => 'DESC', // or ASC
        //'pad_counts'        => false,
        //'cache_domain'      => 'core'
      ) );

      if(!empty($attributes)) : ?>
      <div id="tab-specs" class="tab-pane active">
        <div class="spec-table">
          <?php if(!empty($attributes)) : ?>
          <?php
          foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

            $subterms = get_terms('attribute', array(
              'parent'     => $attribute->term_id,
              'hide_empty' => true
            ));
            foreach ( $subterms as $subterm ) {
            ?>
            <div class="spec-row">
              <div class="spec-title">
              <?php
              echo '<a href="'. get_term_link( $subterm->slug, 'attribute' ) . '">' . $subterm->name . '</a>';
              $atts = get_terms('attribute', array(
                'parent'     => $subterm->term_id,
                'hide_empty' => true
              ));
              ?>
              </div>
              <div class="spec-desc">
              <?php
                foreach ( $atts as $att ) {
                  echo '<a href="'. get_term_link( $att->slug, 'attribute' ) . '">' . $att->name . '</a>';
                }
              ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
          }
          ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: In the foreach loop, does changing get_terms to wp_get_post_terms narrow it to just the post?

Comment: what do you mean? wp_get_post_terms narrows the first loop to just the post, but afterwards it seems the associative link is lost

Comment: Sorry I meant get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'attribute' ). get_terms() is going to get all the terms in a taxonomy. ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

get_the_terms gets those in the post. ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

Comment: So basically the issue I am having is getting terms in seperate levels e.g. Parent -> Child Terms -> Child Terms, foreach level I have custom HTML as you can see as well. What a struggle, I have tried get_the_terms, the problem is getting the terms of the parent that are only part of the current post.